# Call using an app when uibutton is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have an app that displays a telephone number, and that number is in a uibutton. When the button is clicked, I want it to call. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: How have you tried doing it?

Comment: @Wain, I haven't tried yet

Comment: So you need to google search and try something, then ask a specific question here, showing code, if you have a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the text from the button into an NSUrl and pass it in:

```
let url = NSURL(string: button.currentTitle)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

If when your selector for the button is called it passes the button into the method. So you can just grab it from there.

```
func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let button : UIButton = sender as? UIButton {
        if let url = NSURL(string: button.titleLabel?.text) {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
        }
    }
}
```